# Sort XmlDocument by attribute using C#

Tags: c#, sorting, xmldocument

I have an XmlDocument that looks something like this;

```
<Root>
  <file id="1" amount="10" att="0" />
  <file id="2" amount="20" att="0"/>
  <file id="3" amount="40" att="0"/>
  <file id="4" amount="30" att="0"/>
  <file id="5" amount="10" att="0"/>
</Root>
```

After sort, it should look like this:

```
<Root>
  <file id="3" amount="40" att="0"/>
  <file id="4" amount="30" att="0"/>
  <file id="2" amount="20" att="0"/>
  <file id="1" amount="10" att="0"/>
  <file id="5" amount="10" att="0"/>
</Root>
```

I generate an XmlDocument;

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
```

I then generate an XmlNodeList;

```
XmlNodeList xAmount = xDoc.SelectNodes("Root/file[@att='0']");
```

I then do a for loop and build a multidimensional array.

```
amtArray = new int[xAmount.Count, 2];

for (int i = 0; i < xAmount.Count; i++)
{
    amtArray[i,0] = xAmount[i].Attribute["id"].Value;
    amtArray[i,1] = xAmount[i].Attribute["amount"].Value;
}
```

I can attempt a sort at any given point where possible.

sort the whole XmlDocument, xDoc

or

sort the XmlNodeList, xAmount

or

sort the multidimensional array.

I'm asking if there is a way to sort the whole XmlDocument or the XmlNodeList.

Comment: And your question? Or just want us to write it for you?

Comment: Ya, I was wondering what a solution might be.

Comment: I'm currently working on sorting a multidimensional array built from the XML data, but I was thinking there might be a simple XmlDocument Sort solution I'm not aware of. My searches have yielded no result, so maybe it's just not possible.

Comment: Look into LINQ for XML, XDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find [Linq2Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) easier to use..

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var newxDoc = new XElement("Root", xDoc.Root
                                   .Elements()
                                   .OrderByDescending(x => (int)x.Attribute("amount"))
                                   .ThenBy(x=>(int)x.Attribute("id"))
                            );
string xml = newxDoc.ToString();
```

OUTPUT:

```
<Root>
  <file id="3" amount="40" att="0" />
  <file id="4" amount="30" att="0" />
  <file id="2" amount="20" att="0" />
  <file id="1" amount="10" att="0" />
  <file id="5" amount="10" att="0" />
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes I've seen this solution. In the future, I'll look into Linq, but I just can't work it into my current project. I'd have to rewrite a lot of existing methods.